# Disable data annotations when using fluent validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, data-annotations, fluentvalidation

In my app I'm using FluentValidator and recently added swagger to document my APIs. I want to provide information about the request model, and for that I'm using data annotations, but only want to use them as visualizers for my swagger UI, without actually provide the chance for ASP to execute them. Basically I only want the FluentValidation to take effect.

In the docs there is this section https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#compatibility-with-asp-net-s-built-in-validation which states that you can use fluentValidation with another validaton provider, or if you want you can disable other validation providers (which I want)

following is my service configuration

```
serviceDescriptors
   .AddControllersWithViews(configuration =>
    {
       configuration.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized));
       configuration.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden));
       configuration.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/json"));
       configuration.Filters.AddService<AccountAuthorizerFilter>();
    })
   .AddFluentValidation(config =>
    {                 
       config.RunDefaultMvcValidationAfterFluentValidationExecutes = false;                
       config.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = false;
    })
   .AddControllersAsServices()
```

Now when making a request which has a modle like this

```
public class RequestMolde
{
     [Required]
     public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

The ASP.NET model validator provider kicks in.
Any ideas on how to disable this, but still be able to display on the swagger UI the required fileds, or any other annotations ?

Comment: How about using your fluent validator configurations for generating swagger docs? That way, you wouldn't need to duplicate your validation logic with attributes. Looks like there's a project that does just what I said: https://github.com/zymlabs/nswag-fluentvalidation I haven't used this library myself so I can't vouch for anything but I like the idea. You can search for other projects like this or implement it yourself.

Comment: Being an `int`, isn't it from a validation perspective implicitly required? e.g., if you provided null it'd fail on model binding, rather than model validation?